# Group By Clause for multiple groups

Tags: mysql

I have a dummy dataset as follows(for representation purpose only),

```
Number  Duration
1123456     65
1156789     34
116578      56
119870      34
225678      56
228765      78
229474      45
339484940   34
4477595     67
33748494    23
33748494    67
4478900     44
5589090     34
```

What I need to do is get the sum after group by first two numbers. Mean that I need to group by 11,22,33,44 and 55. After group by further I need to make 11 and 22 group as John, both 33 and 44 group as Mike, 55 group as Ann.

Here what I need finally,

```
User    Total
John    368 //sum up the all the durations which starts with  11 or 22
Mike    201 //sum up the all the durations which starts with  33 or 44
Ann      34//sum up the all the durations which starts with 55
```

Here is my try,

```
select left(Number,2) as User, 
       sum(Duration) as Total 
from user_data 
group by left(Number,2);
```

But I have no idea to go beyond that. Can someone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT (CASE
            WHEN left(number, 2) IN ('11', '22') THEN 'John'
            WHEN left(number, 2) IN ('33', '44') THEN 'Mike'
            WHEN left(number, 2) IN ('55') THEN 'Ann'
            ELSE NULL END ) AS name,
       sum(duration)
FROM numberDuration
GROUP BY name;
```

Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE numberDuration
(
    number   INT,
    duration INT
);
INSERT INTO numberDuration
VALUES (1123456, 65),
       (1156789, 34),
       (116578, 56),
       (119870, 34),
       (225678, 56),
       (228765, 78),
       (229474, 45),
       (339484940, 34),
       (4477595, 67),
       (33748494, 23),
       (33748494, 67),
       (4478900, 44),
       (5589090, 34);
```

Result:

```
John,368
Mike,235
Ann,34
```